# Geographical data per ip command line tool

Tags: linux, geoip

Is there any (preferably FOSS) command line tool that provides geographical information per requested IP?

Online [example](http://freegeoip.net/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `geoiplook` up command, but it returns only Country.
if you are using Debian/Ubuntu try installing as follows.

```
apt-get install geoip-bin
```